# W10 Backup with documents, images, downloads...and Ubuntu?

Tags: partitioning, backup

I am pretty new using Ubuntu.

I have been convinced for years that W10( like all previous versions of W) is a space devourer. And due to the abnormal size of the OS, unnecessarily claims a lot of space which gradually leaves your PC or Laptop with less and less memory to do its job.

With the previous two things in mind, I am trying to gather enough practical info to turn my PC(W10) into an Ubuntu Pc.
I'm happy to take the time to make that transition( with the help of your expertise) smooth as possible.
Hence, I'm already testing Ubuntu(20.04) LTS on an older Laptop(Acer Aspire"2012).
And I like it just fine..although I still have to get used to the OS and especially the layout of the desktop and learning how to install software and especially if that software is not part of the U 20.04 software package by default, etc.

So I still have a lot to learn about Ubuntu 20.04 ;-)

1.) I would like to know how to take the contents of the folders in W10; images, documents and downloads with me to Ubuntu?
I must immediately add...I have no space on the PC for a dual boot W10/ Ubuntu.

2.) And if I put U 20.04 on that PC will I have access to my video collection which is many GB in size?
That collection is stored a so called Data-Partition, the D-drive
I mean...with a fresh U 20.04 installation...I want to have access to that video collection without any problems and watch videos from it with my family.

Greetz, Oliver

Comment: If you are going to make this transition have you got a separate disk on which to make a backup of all the data you care about? You would be well advised to backup before making any changes. Then it would be a simple case of installing Ubuntu to the entire disk and copying your data back to a convenient location in the Linux filesystem. Videos will play fine but don’t take my word for it. Try one out on your old laptop.

Answer (score 2):

## Q 1.)

> I would like to know how to take the contents of the folders in W10; images, documents and downloads with me to Ubuntu? I must
> immediately add...I have no space on the PC for a dual boot W10/
> Ubuntu.

### Answer

1. Invest in an USB external drive. If you can afford it, buy an external SSD. The SSDs are faster than mechanical hard drives. Buy two if you can. You should have more than one backup.
2. Copy all the images, documents, downloads in your external USB drive(s). Copy all your videos in the D: drive into the external USB drives as well.

**Don't use Windows backup program or any third party backup program to back up your files for this purpose.** Just copy and paste or drag and drop the folders. Or create new folders and copy and paste files in them.

3. Install Ubuntu using the default option of deleting Windows 10. This option will delete all the partitions in your internal drive including C: and D:. Therefore it is very important that you have two copies of your images, music, video, documents, etc. in two external drives.

## Q 2.)

> And if I put U 20.04 on that PC will I have access to my video
> collection which is many GB in size? That collection is stored a so
> called Data-Partition, the D-drive I mean...with a fresh U 20.04
> installation...I want to have access to that video collection without
> any problems and watch videos from it with my family.

### Answer

Windows is not always very clear what is a separate hard drive (or SSD) and what is a partition as partitions are called C: Drive, D: Drive etc. If your D: Drive is a data partition in the same physical hard drive, then it will get deleted if you install Ubuntu using the default options of erasing Windows.

It is possible to install Ubuntu while preserving other partitions such as the D: Drive. For that you will need to use the **Something Else** option. This is the advanced option where you will have to tell the installer which partitions to delete and what partitions to create and how to format the new partition so that Ubuntu can use it as the system partition. If you select the wrong partition then you may be deleting the data partition (D:) instead of the Windows OS partition (C:).

The **Something Else** option requires deeper understanding of how partitions are named and mounted in Ubuntu. I do not recommend this for someone who is "pretty new using Ubuntu."

Even for long-time users of Ubuntu, mistakes happen. Therefore, I recommend that you make external USB drive backups even if you feel comfortable using the **Something Else** option.

#### Where is my D: Drive?

If the D: Drive is located in a separate physical hard disk (or SSD) OR if you used the **Something Else** option correctly then D: Drive will not be deleted by the installation process. However, Ubuntu will not call it "D:". You will have to set Ubuntu up to mount the partition (previously called the D: Drive) with a mountpoint. Mountopints are empty folders created specifically for mounting partitions. You may also want this partition to be mounted automatically when you turn the computer on and Ubuntu boots. Once the partition is mounted it can be accessed like any folder in Ubuntu.

Once you have copied your videos back into the computer from the external USB drive, Or once you have set up the data partition to mount when the computer boots, you should be able to play the videos using an application like VLC. As others have pointed out you should test with a sample video on your other computer to make sure the videos work with VLC or something similar.

Hope this helps

Comment: Very awsem, @user68186, Thank you for giving all these tips. I can work with them.

Comment: @OliverHoman if you think your question has been answered then accept the answer by clicking on the gray check mark ✔️ next to the answer and turn it green ✅. This will indicate that your problem is solved and help others.

Answer (score 1):

Linux can read the MS Windows file system, ntfs, without issues, and support for ntfs will soon even be included in the kernel, so it will perform optimally.

Transferring your data is a matter of having a copy on an external disk. That disk can then be connected to Ubuntu, and the personal data can then be copied from the removable disk onto the computer, in folders in your user Home directory.

Besides ntfs, Linux also supports the old FAT32 (vfat), and already has kernel support for extfat. So any drives formatted in these file systems can be read from and written to by Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 for recommending backups.

Comment: Very nice that you give these tips, @vanadum,that helps me move forward!

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to AskUbuntu.
 If you have space left on your D:\ you can move your documents, downloads, music and pictures to it. So on your C:\ there is only Windows and the programs you use. Your D:\ ( NTFS) is read/writable by Ubuntu, so that is no problem.
 If you want a more Windowsy look, give Kubuntu, Lubuntu (very light and fast) or Xubuntu a try. They are just like Ubuntu, under the hood, but with a different Desktop Environment. The program launcher is more or less like the startbutton like Windows has. So you probably feel more 'at home'.
Keep in mind that Linux based systems mostly use different software than Windows. Practice with the software you will need to do your things first. 
The softwarecenter is where you can search for programs. It is very easy to use.

Comment: **In any case you should have backups**. Even for experienced users a single mistake or distraction is all it takes to overwrite the "data partition".